# ASP Listview. How to hide a table row using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

If i use the following markup for my ListView it will ignore the css properties on the div.
What is it i don't get here ?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("RowNumber")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Desc")%></td>
    </tr>
    <div style="display: none; visibility: hidden">
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("RowNumber")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Desc")%></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("RowNumber")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Desc")%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none;">
        <td><%# Eval("RowNumber")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("Desc")%></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Alex is correct, but the reason is your HTML is invalid. You cannot wrap a TR in a DIV.

Comment: Thanks for completing with the reason.